# I just lost /var/lib/dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg, repository, apt-cache

I have an empty `/var/lib/dpkg` and as consequence both `apt` and `dpkg` are starting to complain about everything and with every simple task I would like to do with them: there is a way to rebuild that directory ?

I simply got this directory deleted ... don't ask why, it's something too "experimental" that I should not have try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a backup you can restore from, no.  You will have to reinstall.

Comment: I noticed some automated backups under `/var/backups/` but they are causing more troubles than benefits, also this way the rebuilding and the re-indexing of all the packages just takes forever ...

Comment: do you know where i can download the most up to date iso of Precise so I don't have to re-download all the updates separately ?