# Removal steam 64 didn't work ubuntu 14.04.3LTS 64bit

Tags: 14.04, steam

As I mention in Q.

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
sudo apt-get remove steam-launcher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam-launcher
```

---

If I run `steam` from terminal, it is working.

```
$which steam    
/usr/bin/steam
```

[image]

---

## I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217872/how-do-i-remove-steam) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640285/cant-remove-steam)

---

## Update 1.

As @Ravan said:

```
$ apt-cache policy steam
steam:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.0.0.45-1ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     1:1.0.0.45-1ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
     1:1.0.0.45-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
```

---

Please, let me know If I have to provide more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove icon of uninstalled application from application lens in Dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170468/how-can-i-remove-icon-of-uninstalled-application-from-application-lens-in-dash)

Comment: Not it's not. Steam still working as i mention in Q part 5

Comment: [edit] post and add output of `apt-cache policy steam`

Comment: @Ravan Updated!

Comment: please try solution provided in linked post and report back :)

Comment: @Ravan Oh i did  follown all command from linkend's solution. All parts are command's result

Comment: @BeGood, Could you check if it is a link and which package it comes from, `ls -l /usr/bin/steam ; dpkg -S /usr/bin/steam` , for quick advance, if it is a link then `dpkg -S put-link-target-here`

Comment: @Sneetsher This is the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13503330/). I don't understand about link and package ... forgive me, I am a newbie!

Comment: @BeGood, i have added option two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [the related chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/32148/), The OP will merge his questions which are related to same root cause, deleted `/var/lib/dpkg` by mistake.

You have already recovered for some files like `status`. But you are still missing package info files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

Most important is the installed file `*.list`. Without them `dpkg` will remove the package from the `status` file (for purge) and flag them as `deinstall` (for remove), but it will not remove the files.

Options:

- It is recommended to reinstall the system as in this similar case: [I just lost /var/lib/dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287569/i-just-lost-var-lib-dpkg)
- Or If you have good Internet connection, flag all installed packages to be reinstalled. (like an upgrade operation).

  For easy way, use `synaptic`
- Dirty way: Generate the `*.list` files and live with it. I couldn't manage to filter configuration files for each package. So remember any future `apt-get remove` will be like `apt-get purge`.

  1. Install `apt-file`

     ```
     sudo apt-get install apt-file
     ```
  2. Update package contents lists

     ```
     apt-file update
     ```
  3. Generate list for each installed package, quiet long operation (I didn't have time to optimize)

     ```
     mkdir file_lists_deleteme
     dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' bash -c "apt-file -F list '{}' > file_lists_deleteme/'{}'.preformat"

     cd file_lists_deleteme
     for f in *.preformat; do awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' $f > $(basename $f .preformat).list ; done
     ```
  4. Change ownership to root and install them to the system

     ```
     sudo chown root:root file_lists_deleteme/*.list
     sudo cp file_lists_deleteme/*.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/
     ```

---

For Steam & Flareget as they are not on the installed package list, the better is the reinstall them then purge/remove again.

Yes, you will see some dpkg complains (if you have chosen the dirty fix) like:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing flareget, directory '/usr/share/lintian/overrides' not empty so not removed
```

when it tries to remove some non-empty system folder. They are just warning & harmless, never mind about them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install it and then purge it

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install steam
sudo apt-get purge steam
sudo dpkg -P steam
```

---

If install fails you can try forcing it or using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam`

Comment: Can't `sudo apt-get install steam` and can't `sudo apt-get install --reinstall steam`

Comment: what error does it say when you try to install it?

Comment: Their is also the ugly way of doing it using locate.
`sudo updatedb && sudo locate steam`

Comment: Steam still working.... http://paste.ubuntu.com/13467649/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6 && sudo apt-get install steam -y` The reason you want to install it is because if it will install correctly it will uninstall correctly.

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: if you cannot find lib32bz2-1.0 then run `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 lib32stdc++6 && sudo apt-get install steam -y`

Comment: If the command is too long please post it in [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Well I'm not sure then. If you want to get rid of all the files dealing with steam you can find them with the locate command and delete them individually.  You did also try `sudo apt-get check` right? I doubt it will find anything, but it may.

Comment: If you want me provide  more information please let me knoow